# swift How can I convert Firestore timestamp to date display

Tags: ios

I want to add the date of publication to the article, but how to modify it is displayed as a timestamp instead of a date, where should I add the code to display the date instead.

FeedVC

```
func getDatas(){
 if let timestamp = document.get("timestamp") as? Int{
                                        
 let post = Post(email: email, caption: caption, imageUrl: imageURL, timestamp: timestamp)
                                    self.postArray.append(post)
...
...
...
                                        


 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! 
...
...

        cell.timeLabel.text = String(postArray[indexPath.row].timestamp) 
        
      
        
        return cell
    }
```

post

```
import Foundation

struct Post{
    var email:String
    var caption:String
    var imageUrl:String
    var timestamp:Int

    
    init(email:String,caption:String,imageUrl:String,timestamp:Int) {
        self.email = email
        self.caption = caption
        self.imageUrl = imageUrl
        self.timestamp = timestamp
    }
}
```

Comment: Timestamp is an `Int`? What does it represents? Number of seconds from 70? Then, init a `Date` from it, and use a `DateFormatter` to transform that Date into a String in the format you want.

Comment: If the timestamp is not an INT, how can I modify the code to put (Firestore->timestamp
1656317129) upload to IOS and show as date? Thanks for your help

Comment: `Date` is just a higher level to represent a date with a timestamp (number of seconds since 70 for the main cases). A lot of languages use a timestamp. So create a date with that timestamp. The string you want, is just a "human readable" interpretation of it (localized). So as said, use a `Date` (there is an `init` with a timestamp), and then use a `DateFormatter` (which can be used to transform `Date` into `String` or `String` into `Date`).

Comment: Now, if in Firebase, you saved a `TimeStamp` object, there is a `dateValue()`, so insted of initializing your struct with an `Int`, initialize it with a `Date`?

Comment: Can you please tell me how to convert it? I don't understand how to modify it, thank you very much

Comment: @ERIC, Can you please provide any one Timestamp value you get?

Comment: let timestamp = Int(Date().timeIntervalSince1970)

Comment: I don't know what code to add in which view to upload the (timestamp) of Firestore
1656317129) The download is converted into a date and displayed in the IOS article, which code should be added in the "tableview" code, "post", or "cell"?